# An audio distortion problem when I use javax.sound package

Tags: java, audio

I am working on an audio speaker project. I receive the real-time `byte[]` message from the front-end thus I built a speaker instance with `javax.sound` package to play the message.

The problem is: I get distorted audio when I change the sound channel number to `2` (that means stereo audio). Should I arrange some kind of stereo microphone or other specific devices to fix it? Or my way to initialize the speaker is not correct?

Here is the code to initialize the speaker:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class SpeakerWriter {
    public static final AudioFormat FORMAT_1 = new AudioFormat(44100.0f, 16, 1, true, false);
    //16 is sample size in bits & 1 is channel number 
    private static AudioFormat format = FORMAT_1;
    private SourceDataLine speakers;

    public SourceDataLine getSpeakers() {
        try {
            DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, format);
            speakers = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            speakers.open(format);
            speakers.start();

        }
        catch(LineUnavailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return speakers;
    }

}
```

By the way, I reconstructed the code with Golang but the problem still exists.

Comment: Hey Jiayu, welcome to Stack Overflow! Try to stick to relevant tags related to the context you're giving us in the examples (e.g. you're only providing Java code but tagging your question with `go`).

Comment: I'm not clear I understand the question. Is the data playing back correctly with channel set to 1 and distorted with the channel set to 2? If so, are you adding additional data for the new track, or expecting Java to provide the data? Otherwise, the SourceDataLine is going to assume the mono track itself is left and right audio PCM when you set the channel count to 2.

Comment: Hi Phil, your understanding is correct. Neither more data was added to the new track nor java offered new data. So the speaker's configuration is well and what process for the original data should I do to trans the mono sound to stereo? Should I buy a stereo microphone to collect double-track data? I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Do you know for sure that your file is BigEndian? If not, I would try changing the BigEndian value to 'false'. I think this is considerably more common, and getting it wrong tends to create distortion.

Comment: Thanks! I've set the format as LittlelEndian in the code.  ```public static final AudioFormat FORMAT_1 = new AudioFormat(44100.0f, 16, 1, true, false);```  The last parameter means setting the BigEndian value to ```false```. And the ```true``` value before it means signed data.

Comment: Thus I think the Endianness is not the point.